# SugarCRM DB tables timeperiods

Tags: mysql, crm, sugarcrm

how crm add to table "timeperiods", is do automatic or I need add this every Quarter

Comment: Hi Michal, can you be a little more clear about the issue you are facing, and provide what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

The rows in the `timeperiods` table are generated by the standard "Create Future TimePeriods" scheduler. So if you have it running by the default interval they should be generated automatically.